# Rails5 migration : Table has no foreign key for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

After migrating my Rails 4.2 app to Rails 5, when I try to migrate from a new database i get the following error

> Table 'objectives' has no foreign key for development_plan

Here are the significant migrations:

1. Creates the foreign_key using add_reference

   ```
   class AddDevelopmentPlanToObjectives < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       add_reference :objectives, :development_plan, index: true, foreign_key: true
     end
   end
   ```
2. Removes the foreign key (generates error)

   ```
   class DropDevelopmentPlans < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       Objective.all.each do |objective|
         company = objective.owner.company
         company.cycles.create name: '4Q 2015', begin_at: Date.today, end_at: 1.year.from_now, current: true unless company.current_cycle
         company.reload
         objective.update cycle: company.current_cycle
       end
       remove_foreign_key :objectives, :development_plan
       remove_reference :objectives, :development_plan, index: true
       drop_table :development_plans
     end
   end
   ```

The migration breaks on `remove_foreign_key :objectives, :development_plan`

Anyone had this problem? This also happens on other similar migrations...

Comment: So your migration adds the foreign key then a late one removes it?

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized that the firs one is the `Add` and the second one is the `Drop`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe **to_table** should be inclinated in plural form:

```
remove_foreign_key :objectives, to_table: :development_plans
```

Please refer to [rails api docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-remove_foreign_key).

Answer (score 0):

Referencing this article: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/01/migrations-are-versioned-in-rails-5.html

Rails 5 adds a version to migration classes thus:

Migration generated in Rails 5.0:

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
 ...
end
```

If you don't have that it will attempt to us a compatibility layer. While that compatibility layer was targeted at Rails 4.2 and that's what it should default to according to that article, I would try changing your migrations to all use:

```
class AddDevelopmentPlanToObjectives < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
  ....
```

See if that helps. If not I would change your migrations to fit the changes outlined for v5.0

```
class AddDevelopmentPlanToObjectives < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :objectives, :development_plan, foreign_key: true
  end
end

class DropDevelopmentPlans < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    Objective.all.each do |objective|
      company = objective.owner.company
      company.cycles.create name: '4Q 2015', begin_at: Date.today, end_at: 1.year.from_now, current: true unless company.current_cycle
      company.reload
      objective.update cycle: company.current_cycle
    end
    remove_foreign_key :objectives, :development_plan
    remove_reference :objectives, :development_plan
    drop_table :development_plans
  end
end
```